# Simple html vs extension methods in Razor (preference)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

For Simple tags in MVC Razor do you prefer to use simple HTML or use extension methods
eg

```
<label for="male">Male</label> 
Or   
@Html.Label("male", "Male")
```

I feel it is sometime more easier to use the simple HTML.
Extension methods make sense when you want to do some custom code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends. If the `male` element you are associating this label to is rendered with a html helper like: `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Male)` then I would use a `Html.LabelFor` and keep the lambdas and strong typing. Also I would never use:

```
@Html.Label("male", "Male")
```

I would use a view model and a strongly typed version:

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Male)
```

and I would decorate my view model property with the `[DisplayName]` attribute so that I can control message on my view model:

```
[DisplayName("foo bar")]
public string Male { get; set; }
```

So there are like many different possible scenarios. I could also sometimes simply use static HTML and no helpers (currently can't think of such scenario but I am sure it exists).

Answer (score 0):

You could use DisplayFor. It's another way to show your data.

Comment: :The question was not the alternative for label but what one is the preference for all the simple html like label,textbox,input.Do you prefer simple Html or Razor helper methods.